# PostgreSQL User table, benefits of user_id?

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

I am creating a table to store my user's info in a psql database, what are the benefits of saving a serialized user_id if the username has to be unique. In other words, why cant the username be the primary key?

This is directly from the PostgreSQL docs:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        last_login TIMESTAMP 
);
```

Comment: Would you feel safe searching records for a particular user whose username is an SQL injection attempt? or that contains spaces? or an emoji? or characters that you can't see? or in a language using a different alphabet than yours? Computers (usually) don't mind, humans do.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are easier/faster/less expensive to sort, search, and compare than strings. If you only have 5 users you may not notice the difference. At 10,000 users you'll feel it. Big time. Internally, you should use that key for everything, the username is only for authentication. It's not user `bobsmith` it's user 347.

That's the primary reason everyone uses an integer as an id/primary key. There are cases for using uuids instead, but those are stored as byte arrays, not a string (unless it's nosql, which changes all the rules).

Comment: "*At 10,000 users you'll feel it. Big time*" - hardly. At 10 million maybe

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't mean that your query would be non-functional, you can certainly scale quite a ways.. but you start to see the sideeffects much earlier than 10 million.

Answer (score 0):

> why cant the username be the primary key?

While it should be unique, it's not suitable as a primary key in this case.

In general, primary key values should never change. Any user provided value is highly likely to change at some point or another. If you make the username the primary key and then have other tables *referencing* your `accounts` table, you would have to change the username in each and every table. Using a generated primary key saves you from that trouble. If you made `username` the primary key, you probably would have to tell your users they can't change their username to make things easier for your.

Foreign keys are another reason why people prefer numbers instead of strings, as they make the *referencing* tables a bit smaller. Probably not a huge difference and depending on the type of queries you run, it might not even be noticeable. But still.

---

Note that the use of the `serial` "data type" is [disouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) in favor of standard compliant `identity` columns.